# I have already installed clang, but can not use "cc" command. What have I missed?

Tags: linux, clang

I am using linux mint 18.1. I didn't install clang by apt tool but downloaded a Pre-Built Binaries edition from [LLVM Releases](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). It's newer and includes libc++.

Anyway, after downloading, I moved them to "/usr/local". Command "clang -v" tells me some information about clang.

```
vita-nove@Alienware ~ $ clang -v
clang version 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

So I think it was set down correctly. Problem is here: I can not use "cc" command, bash shows:

```
The program 'cc' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcc
 * clang
 * tcc
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Usually `cc` is just a symlink to `gcc`/`clang`. You can create it yourself using `ln -s`, if you really need that, but I doubt there is any difference in Clang's behavior when it is ran as `cc` or as `clang`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I mean, "The program 'cc' can be found in clang" really confuses me. The reason why it contains is because wanna care user's habit, so there should be no difference between them right? Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: It might be so that `cc` symlink can be somehow switched between clang and gcc, when those packages are installed. This gives you a way to change the compiler on the fly. But yes, running `clang` as `cc` is the same as running `clang`.